# C# Method Attribute cannot contain a Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, attributes

IntelliSense is telling me "Expression cannot contain anonymous methods or lambda expressions." Really? I was not aware of this imposed limitation. Is this correct? I guess I'm looking for a sanity check here...

```
public delegate bool Bar(string s);

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class Foo : Attribute
{
    public readonly Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Usage
{
    [Foo(b => b == "Hello World!")]        // IntelliSense Complains here
    public Usage()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about what you would expect this to do.

Comment: My intention was only to allow a simple mapping for some configuration purposes.

Comment: In this example, what would be mapped to what? Would the `Usage` method be mapped to the lambda in the `Foo` attribute? When would the lambda execute? It's not clear to me but this might be an interesting idea...

Comment: Well I'm really just prototyping some ideas for a DI scheme (no I can't use Ninject unfortunately), so this was just one idea I was exploring. I ran across the IntelliSense issue, and I was just completely unaware of the limitation. No biggy though, the configuration will just have to reside else-where

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes this is correct.  Attribute values are limited to constants of the following types

- Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
- string
- System.Type
- enums
- object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)
- One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of a bummer.

Comment: Meh. And there I was thinking I'd finally come up with a solution I found acceptable for INotifyPropertyChanged. Ah well, back to the drawing board.

Comment: The link is dead