# Checking custom attribute parameters at design/build time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, lambda

I have a `CustomAuthorize` attribute that checks to see if a user has access to functionality (a user or role can be associated with items from a hierarchical set of functions).

For a given action method...

```
[CustomAuthorize("Security.Admin.ManageWidgets.Update")]
```

This works but I'm concerned that changes to the Security object could cause problems that won't be detected until run-time.  I realize that I can write unit tests to mitigate this risk but I would like to know if it is possible to check the attribute parameter at compile time.  I also like having Intellisense help me type this expression.

Ideally, I could pass a lambda expression.

```
[CustomAuthorize(i => i.Admin.ManageWidgets.Update)]
```

Unfortunately this [is not currently possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411122/c-method-attribute-cannot-contain-a-lambda-expression) ([additional info from Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/254057/allowing-expression-t-in-attributes-parameters)).

I also tried encapsulating the expression hoping it would be evaluated and then passed to the attribute as a string, but this also failed to compile with the same error (*Expression cannot contain anonymous methods or lambda expressions*).

```
[CustomAuthorize(LambdaToString(i => i.Admin.ManageWidgets.Update))]
```

**How can I add some design-time / build-time support for my custom attribute parameters?**

Comment: +1 for an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to create custom classes with string properties, ending up with code similar to BennyM's, but generated automatically.

Comment: This might have put me on the right track - my Security object is already auto-generated and I can add a const to each class/subclass that has the fully-qualified name.  It's not exactly verifying that the string is okay but since it's auto-generated I can safely make that assumption (and I get intellisense).

Answer (score 3):

A Static class with constants.

```
public static class Rights
{
    public const string UpdateWidgets = "UpdateWidgets";
}
```

Also include unittests for the methods which are decorated with them and you'll be pretty good.

```
[CustomAuthorize(Rights.UpdateWidgets)]
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't check these sorts of things at compile time - the best you could hope for is a post-build step that checks this via reflection.

You could instead supply a type and a method name, like this:

```
[CustomAuthorize(typeof(Security.Admin.ManageWidgets), "Update")]
```

But seeing as you still need to type the name of the method its debatable what benefit this really gains you.